# process azure queue based on timer and on queue length

Tags: azure, azure-queues, azure-triggers

I want to run a function when my azure queue reaches x length or has not been looked at for y minutes. ie:
I have a queue myQueue, which a webhook is adding messages to. I want to process the queue if it reaches X messages in length or if it hasn't been processed for Y minutes (this is incase there are less than X messages sat in queue).
Am I missing something obvious? I can see queue triggers, but that is for every message that enters queue (I think?) or timer triggers that will do my time part but not a mix.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Queue Trigger is to trigger a function whenever a message arrives into a queue. There's no 'batch' queue trigger, so you either work with a time trigger that runs every x seconds and check for the queue length and start processing, or you live with the original queue trigger.

Comment: Thanks @Thaigo, Can you limit the queue trigger to only fire after X number of messages are recieved? or it simply triggered for every message added to the queue? I have been searching, I'm just a bit confused by it!

Comment: "The Queue Trigger is to trigger a function whenever a message arrives into a queue." You can't wait for X messages to arrive before starting process it. If that's your requirement you should use Time Trigger and check if the queue contains the minimum number of messages  you need, and then start the process